# Couchbase : List available Buckets, scopes and collection available in a Cluster with Java SDK 3

Tags: java, collections, couchbase, bucket, scopes

Working on a Java application I would like to list all available buckets / scopes and collections available for choice by the user. This is written using Couchbase Java SDK 3.0

I did not find any resources on the web.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cluster has a [`buckets()`](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/Cluster.html#buckets--) method that returns a BucketManager. You can use this manager to get a map of bucket names to bucket info. If you want only the names, grab them from this map's keyset.

To access scope/collection info, first get a Bucket from the Cluster. The you can call the bucket's [`collections()`](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html#collections--) method to get the bucket's CollectionManager. From there you can get all the scopes, and query each scope to find out which collections it contains.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.connect("localhost", "Administrator", "password");
cluster.waitUntilReady(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

BucketManager bucketManager = cluster.buckets();
Set<String> bucketNames = bucketManager.getAllBuckets().keySet();

for (String bucketName : bucketNames) {
  Bucket bucket = cluster.bucket(bucketName);
  System.out.println("Bucket: " + bucketName);

  CollectionManager collectionManager = bucket.collections();
  for (ScopeSpec scope : collectionManager.getAllScopes()) {
    System.out.println("  Scope: " + scope.name());

    for (CollectionSpec collection : scope.collections()) {
      System.out.println("    Collection: " + collection.name());
    }
  }
}
```

This code throws `FeatureNotAvailableException` if the server does not support collections.